# Access input of a different function but in same contract

Tags: solidity, remix

Is there a way for a function B() to have access to the input given at function A(), knowing function A() and function B() belong to the same contract XPTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the inputs to function B:

```
function A (uint256 foo, uint256 bar) public {
  B(foo, bar);
}
    
function B (uint256 foo, uint256 bar) internal {
  // do something with foo, bar
}
```